# Which is pool joomla component which user can vote?

Tags: joomla

I'm looking for joomla component which allow user upload photos in their profile, then another user can comment and vote those photos.

any help thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Phoca Gallery](http://www.phoca.cz/phocagallery), Its free and open source and highly customizable.